# How to deploy JavaFX application using IntelliJ?

Tags: java, sqlite, intellij-idea, javafx, desktop-application

I have a JavaFX application that I developed and I want to deploy.

My main goal is for the user to install it as quickly as possible, without the need for them to go on the web and download Java or anything else, I just want a nice and clean “Download - Install - Run app”  user experience.

From what I found in the Oracle documentation, a self-contained application seems like the best option for what I want to do. (I might be wrong about this tho and therefore am open to suggestions). However I could not find a complete and explicit step-by-step guide as to how to achieve this. For example, the Oracle documentation mentions modifying the deployment task and “Ant Task Reference” which I have never even heard of and don’t know how to find.

Important mentions: the app will be run on Windows, I used JavaFX 11.0.2 and IntelliJ for development, and SQLite as a local database and I haven’t used Maven or anything like that.

EDIT: As a first step I tried following [these](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html) steps as Andrey also suggested but when I try to build the artifacts i get the following error, which seems to be a known [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200721?_ga=2.152765817.1185537544.1581330088-1919084999.1576153642) and can only be achieved with Java 8 (I am using Java version 13.0.1)

Error:Java FX Packager:

BUILD FAILED

C:\Users\Diana.IdeaIC2018.2\system\compile-server\vn-master_d533d263_temp_\build.xml:3: Problem: failed to create task or type javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:fileset

Cause: The name is undefined.

Action: Check the spelling.

Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.

Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: Please provide a link to the Oracle documentation you are referring to. Hopefully that will help make your question clearer to me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/deploy/self-contained-packaging.html#BCGBFDDC

Comment: Have you tried https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/packaging-javafx-applications.html ?

Comment: Yes, but I has hoping for another way to do it since when I try to build the artifacts it generates an error: Error:Java FX Packager: 
BUILD FAILED
Cause: The name is undefined.  -- which seems to be a known issue (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200721?_ga=2.152765817.1185537544.1581330088-1919084999.1576153642 ) that I haven't found a solution for